# Override function in source file

Tags: c++, macos, design-patterns

I'm building a cross platform application, and I have this:

```
// Gui.h
class View {
protected:
    virtual void doSomething();
};

class Window : public View {
public:
    void doSomethingElseUnrelated();
};
```

Now for each platform, I have my own Gui.cpp file. So there is one Gui.h file, and a Gui.cpp for each platform.

Now on the windows platform, I can just call the `Window` class function `doSomething`.
However, on Mac platform, the implementation for `Window` class and `View` class `doSomething` is different.

So on Mac platform I have to override the `doSomething` function in the `Window` class.

That means I have to add the `doSomething` `Window` class override in the header file. This will then affect all platforms, even though it is only needed on Mac platform.

Is it possible to add the override of `doSomething` in the `Window` class only for Mac platform?

Comment: Override it using `#ifdef` only on Windows, did you try doing that?

Comment: [Factory method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern). Interface with common functionalities, otherwise specific implementation per platform. Use the factory method to create the object based on the underlying OS. Such as `#ifdef _WIN32`...

Answer (score 0):

Abstract Factory Design pattern is the solution for this query.
Have a look at the tested code for similar requirement below:

**Gui.h:**
The header file with the declaration of all the required classes.

```
class drawB // The Abstract Product1 Class(can add similar Abstract Product2 for another actions like mac/windows style screenlock)
{
public:
    virtual void drawButton() = 0;
};

class WindowsStyleButton : public drawB // Product Class 1
{
public:
    virtual void drawButton() override;
};

class MacStyleButton : public drawB // Product Class 2
{
    void drawButton() override;
};

class Gui //Abstract Factory
{
public:
    virtual drawB* createButton() = 0;
};

class WindowsGui : public Gui // Concrete Factory1
{
public:
    drawB* createButton() override;
};

class MacGui : public Gui //Concrete Factory2
{
public:
    drawB* createButton() override;
};
```

**MacGui.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GUI.h"

using namespace std;

void MacStyleButton ::drawButton()
{
    cout << "Drawing a Mac style Button! " << endl;
}

drawB* MacGui ::createButton()
{
    return new MacStyleButton;
}
```

**WindowsGui.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "GUI.h"

using namespace std;

void WindowsStyleButton :: drawButton()
{
    cout << "drawing a Windows style Button! " << endl;
}

drawB* WindowsGui ::createButton()
{
    return new WindowsStyleButton;
}
```

**Main.cpp**

```
/*the Client*/
int main()
    {
    Gui* GuiObject;
    drawB* BtnObject;

#ifdef __APPLE__ //condition check for Mac OS
    GuiObject = new MacGui;
    BtnObject = GuiObject->createButton();
    BtnObject->drawButton();

#elif _WIN32 // Condition check for Windows OS
    GuiObject = new MacGui;
    BtnObject = GuiObject->createButton();
    BtnObject->drawButton();
#else

#endif
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that there is an interesting utility to reduce boilerplate https://github.com/mvpete/eeyore